# Issue with regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have some code that extracts a bunch of data and stores the result into a variable. 
When I try to run a reg expression on it, it is unable to find a match.  But if I dump the variable to screen by doing an echo statement, and then copy all the data from the screen into a variable and run the regex on the new variable then it is able to find 80+ matches.

Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
  require 'HPVC.php';

  $hp = new HPVC('10.14.3.23', '123', '');
  echo "<br>Attempting connection";

  $hp->connect();
  echo "<br>connection succeeded";
  $data = $hp->showPSAll();
  echo "<br>closing connection...";
  $hp->close();
  echo "<br>connection closed.";

  print_r($data);
  $pattern = '/(\w+)(\s*)(\w+\/\w+|\s+)(\s*)(\|)(\s*)(\w+)(\s*)(\w+)(\s*)(\w+|\s+)(\s*)(\w+)(\s*)(\w+)(\s*)(\w+)(\s*)(\d)/i';
  echo '<br>Number of matches: '.preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Here's what the print_r gives in part :(it's really really long!)

```
         connection closed. [24;1H [24;16H [24;1H [?25h [24;16H [24;16Hshow inter [24;16H [?25h [24;26H [24;26Hfaces brie [24;26H [?25h [24;36H [24;36Hf [24;36H [?25h [24;37H [24;0H E [24;1H [24;37H [24;1H [2K [24;1H [?25h [24;1H [1;24r [24;1H Status and Counters - Port Status | Intrusion MDI Flow Bcast Port Type | Alert Enabled Status Mode Mode Ctrl Limit ------ --------- + --------- ------- ------ ---------- ---- ---- ----- A1 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A2 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A3 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A4 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A5 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A6 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A7 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A8 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A9 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A10 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A11 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A12 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A13 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A14 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A15 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A16 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A17 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 [24;1H [2K [24;1H [1;24r [24;1H A18 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A19 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A20 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A21 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A22 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A23 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 A24 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 B1 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 B2 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 B3 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 B4 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 B5 100/1000T | No Yes Down 1000FDx Auto off 0 B6 100/1000T | No Yes
```

Could someone please assist with this issue?

Comment: What's the type of `$data`? It should be a string.

Comment: We need to see the return value of `$hp->showPSAll()` to usefully suggest anything. An explanation of what you want your regex to match would be helpful as well...

Comment: Please post the result of the print_r

Comment: @chris - i've modified my question to include the output.

Comment: Beware of end of line characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your raw data. What you may be copying is slightly different than what is in $data. An example of this might be non-white space characters displaying as white space and then being copied as white space. You might have to dump $data to a file with a binary write and then look at the characters with a hex editor.

I have run into similar problems myself in the past.

Comment: I will save to a file and then examine with Notepad ++ to see what I'm getting...

Comment: yep.  there were lots more spaces in between fields. Although i don't understand why my \s+ doesn't catch it.  I will take a very careful look and then repost a regex question if need be.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the last line with:

```
echo '<br>Number of matches: '.preg_match_all($pattern, print_r($data, true), $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

(The 2nd parameter of `print_r` being `true` returns the output instead of printing it to screen.)

If this solves your problem, then, as others have commented, your problem is that `$data` is not a string, and instead an array, or an object that got `toString`ed when you `print_r`ed.

Comment: hey.  thanks for the suggestion.  but that didn't work.  it's a string... i know because in the showPSAll() method, i'm doing string replace for different values.

Comment: Hm, okay then. Next culprit: special characters that, when copy/pasted from the screen, disappear.  Upvoting @EconCoder's answer.

Comment: I will save to a file and then examine with Notepad ++ to see what I'm getting...